# Rails create multiple records at once from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table `users` with column `cash_balance`.

I have a table `donations` with `sender_id`, `receiver_id`, `amount`.

I have a table `bank_account_deposits` with `user_id` and `amount`.

I have a form to post on `bank_account_deposits`. The form should just be a button.

Each time I submit the form it should create on bank_account_deposits:

- 1 row with current_user_id and cash balance (from users table). This one is easy to create on bank_account_deposits controller create.
- 1 row for each record on donations table where `receiver_id = current_user.id` with values `user_id = sender_id` and `amount = amount`

Any suggestion on how to implement this? Having to loop entries on table donations table and create records from result confuses me.

I know that it does not make sense because everytime I submit the form it will enter same records but I just simplified it here as that's not the point.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also have a look at https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/

or http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop through Donations and create a Deposit inside the loop with data from each donation:

```
def create

  BankAccountDeposit.create(
    user_id: current_user.id, 
    amount: current_user.cash_balance
  )

  Donation.where(receiver_id: current_user.id).each do |donation|
    BankAccountDeposit.create(
      user_id: donation.sender_id, 
      amount: donation.amount
    )
  end

end
```